# Post dynamic checkbox ids with values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, post

Here is a form which contains dynamic checkbox retrieved from database table named "categories". All i am trying is to echo category id + name on a new page. I want all the selected categories with their ID's. the problem is the output shows the category names but it shows the last category id with each name.

**Form**

```
 <form method="post" action="insert_try.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label>Select categories</label>
 <?php
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"select * from categories");
 if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 ?>
 <br><input type="checkbox" name="categories_chk[]" value="<?= $row["cat_name"]; ?>"> <?= $row["cat_name"]; ?>
 <input type="text" name="cat_chk_id" value="<?= $row["cat_id"]; ?>">
  <?php
       }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">  
    </form>
```

**insert_try.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$cat_chk = $_POST['categories_chk'];
$cat_chk_id=$_POST['cat_chk_id'];
foreach ($cat_chk as $checkbox) {
    echo $checkbox;
 }
echo $cat_chk_id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need this but in your case I would do this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {?>
    <br><input type="checkbox" name="categories_chk[<?= $row["cat_id"]; ?>]" value="<?= $row["cat_name"]; ?>"> <?= $row["cat_name"]; ?>
<?php
}
```

See, I set index of `categories_chk` as a category id.

If you `print_r($_POST['categories_chk'])` you will have a key=>value array where key is category id and value is it's name.

You can iterate over it kinda:

```
foreach ($_POST['categories_chk'] as $id => $name) {
    echo 'Category id ' . $id . ' with name ' . $name;
}
```

Of course, I need to mention that `$row["cat_id"]` must be **unique** for such approach, otherwise you will have two same keys in array and the latter overwrites the previous one.